# How to delete liked data based on id using linq?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I want to delete multiple record using linq base on like id I know that delete single id in a one time but I want it delete all data if link id is same. Here is a code below of which are deleting single link id row now all rows.

```
 VFDataClassesDataContext con = new VFDataClassesDataContext(Globals.con);
 LocationSetting LocationSettings = con.LocationSettings.First(w => w.LinkId == 1);
            con.LocationSettings.DeleteOnSubmit(LocationSettings);
            con.SubmitChanges();
```

if I send a id 1 to delete row then if there is a multiple record linked with id 1 then all record will be deleted.

table is like this ID,LinkID,Value,Type,TimeDate

Value is like this

```
1, 0 , USA , R , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
2, 0 , UAE , R , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
3, 0 , AUS , R, 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
4, 1 , SA , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
5, 1 , UA , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
6, 1 , AS , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
7, 2 , SA , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
8, 2 , UA , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
9, 2 , AS , A , 2013-10-25 20:09:29.043
```

this way is a data in same table

Answer (score 1):

Query the items you wish to delete and pass them to the `DeleteAllOnSubmit()` method.

It sounds like you want to delete items where there are more than one with the same `LinkId`.  Group them by `LinkId` and take the items where the group has more than one.

```
var query =
    from ls in context.LocationSettings
    group ls by ls.LinkId into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    from ls in g
    select ls;
context.LocationSettings.DeleteOnSubmit(query);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: hi Jeff nothing happen i try your example

Comment: Can you say with certainty that there are records in your database that have the same `LinkId`s?  If nothing is returned in the query, then there probably isn't anything that needs removing.

Comment: Please see Edited Description